# Is MySQL Group By normally slow?

Tags: mysql

I have a 1.1 million row table (150MB) where each row has a range of columns with one a column having 15 possible states that I am grouping by.

Any select with count is sub 0.05 seconds, for example:

```
SELECT variant, count(*) 
FROM `log`
```

As soon as I `GROUP BY` I go to to 0.7 seconds, for example:

```
SELECT variant, count(*) 
FROM `log` 
GROUP BY variant
```

The variant column has an index. The unique id per row is the primary key.

Not sure if my query is bad or that my web host has poor performance.

PS, I now installed MySQL on a high spec machine and it took 0.55 to run the query. So it look like it's not that slow.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE log;`  I want to see the Engine and datatypes.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT variant, count(*) FROM log GROUP BY variant
```

together with

```
INDEX(variant)
```

will do a *full scan* of the *index*, not the *table*.  That's 1.1M *index* rows, probably much less than 150MB.

0.7s is reasonable for scanning that much stuff.

If `variant` is an `ENUM`, that will take only 1 byte, hence will make the index smaller than if you had, say, `VARCHAR(55)`.  (I can discuss more after seeing `SHOW CREATE TABLE log;`.)